# Nimbus: Cannot find symbol: method getAllClaims in latest version

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus

One part of my program needs an older version of Nimbus (2.21) to run successfully, and one requires a new version (ideally 4.3).

When I try the new version only, I get this output:

```
[ERROR] /src/main/java/com/service/impl/AuthenticationContextImpl.java:[120,64] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getAllClaims()
[ERROR] location: class com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet
```

The relevant line is:

```
String contextJSON = ((JWTClaimsSet) auth.getCredentials()).getAllClaims().get("context").toString();
```

Presumably this functionality has been updated or renamed in the newer versions of Nimbus. How should I be adapting this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution appears to be that getClaims() is the natural upgrade from getAllClaims().

References:

https://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/2.21/com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTClaimsSet.html

https://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.0/com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTClaimsSet.html